# How to parse csv file into multiple csv based on row spacing

Tags: bash, unix

I'm trying to build a airflow DAG and need to split out 7 tables contained in one csv into seven separate csv's.

`dataset1`

| header_a | header_b | header_c |
| --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three |
| One | Two | Three |

```
                         <-Always two spaced rows between data sets
```

`dataset N`                 <-part of csv file giving details on data

| header_d | header_e | header_f | header_g |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| One | Two | Three | Four |
| One | Two | Three | Four |

`out`:
`dataset1.csv`
`datasetn.csv`

Based on my research i think my solution might lie in `awk` searching for the double spaces?

EDIT: In plain text as requested.

```
table1 details1,
table1 details2,
table1 details3,
header_a,header_b,header_c,
1,2,3
1,2,3


tableN details1,
tableN details2,
tableN details3,
header_a, header_b,header_c,header_N,
1,2,3,4
1,2,3,4
```

Comment: Please provide sample input as plain text, not a bunch of markdown tables. Something that can be copy and pasted into a file.

Comment: Apologies I thought markdown tables would be easier. I've added plain text in code block which appear to format correctly and can be pasted directly into a file for reference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Always two spaced rows between data sets

If your CSV file contains blank lines, and your goal is to write out each chunk of records that is separated by those blank lines into individual files, then you could use `awk` with its record separator `RS` set to nothing, which then defaults to treating each "paragraph" as a record. Each of them can then be redirected to a file whose name is based on the record number `NR`:

```
awk -vRS= '{print $0 > ("output_" NR ".csv")}' input.csv
```

This reads from `input.csv` and writes the chunks to `output_1.csv`, `output_2.csv`, `output_3.csv` and so forth.

If my interpretation of your input file's structure (or your problem in general) is wrong, please provide more detail to clarify.

Comment: This this is exactly what I was hoping for, thanks for the pointer in the direction of the ```RS``` operator